Gitlab changelog generate continues to state "no changes" in the output file though my commits show changes marked for changelog
I'm trying to use GitLab's new changelog feature which automatically builds your changelog using your commit history (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/changelogs.html#from-the-gitlab-cli)
Problem #1
Changelog continues to say no changes made
My .gitlab/changelog_config.yml looks like this:
types:
  - feat
  - fix
  - docs
  - refactor
  - performance

categories:
  feat: Features
  fix: Bug fixes
  docs: Documentation
  refactor: Refactor
  performance: Performance improvements
  
template: |
  {% if categories %}
  {% each categories %}
  ### {{ title }}

  {% each entries %}
  - [{{ title }}]({{ commit.web_url }})\
  {% if author.credit %} by {{ author.reference }}{% end %}

  {% end %}

  {% end %}
  {% else %}
  No changes.
  {% end %}

And when I print my previous commits I see (here I replaced actual commit ids with xxxx):
git log --oneline
xxxx (HEAD -> trunk) added a template
yyyy feat: added a template
zzzz new changelog file Changelog: feat
cccc (tag: v1.0.3) docs: testing changelog
eeee docs: adding changelog again
ssss (tag: v1.0.2, origin/trunk) fixed pdm file

I would assume that then my changelog would have something like:
## 1.0.3 (2024-08-06)

Documentation:
- adding changelog again

but when I try glab changelog generate --version v1.0.3, I continue to generate a changelog with no changes:
## 1.0.3 (2024-08-06)

No changes.

Problem #2
When I try to create a changelog with no specified version:
glab changelog generate
I get the following error:
GET https://{gitlab_link}/repository/changelog: 422 {message: Failed to generate the changelog: The requested `version` attribute format is not correct. Use formats such as `1.0.0` or `v1.0.0`.}

but my tags are all in correct format (i think).
The output of git tag is:
v0.1.3
v0.2.11
v0.2.12
v0.2.13
v0.2.14
v0.2.15
v0.2.16
v0.2.17
v0.2.18
v0.2.19
v0.2.20
v0.2.21
v0.2.7
v0.2.8
v0.2.9
v0.3.0
v0.3.1
v0.3.2
v0.3.3
v1.0.0
v1.0.1
v1.0.2
v1.0.3


I figured out the solution to Problem #1 ! Gitlab changelog only picks up commits that have been pushed to the repo, I had (wrongly) assumed the glab changelog command would pick up my local commits.

I believe the solution to Problem #2 is that I still had a wrongly formatted tag name on my repo, even though locally, I had re-named this tag to match the correct naming convention.
